# Get Trajectory from Voronoi Diagram for Polygonal Obstacles

Tags: matlab, voronoi

I'm trying to get the Trajectory from Voronoi Diagram using the library *voronoi* from Matlab. I'm using this code:

`vo` = (all the obstacles from a binary picture, plotted in a figure), where:

- `vo(1,:)` : x-axis points
- `vo(2,:)` : y-axis points

**Code:**

```
figure; hold on;
plot(vo(1,:),vo(2,:),'sr');

[vx,vy] = voronoi(vo(1,:),vo(2,:));

plot(vx,vy,'-b');
```

Obtaining:
[image]

In other words, how can I separate all the useless lines from the real trajectory?

Comment: What do you mean by the "real trajectory"? You want to keep the cell boundaries as determined here but merge cells for points in the same polygon?

Comment: I mean the blue lines that are not in horizontal and vertical directions. That is, the blue lines that surround the polygons (squares and rectangles in this case).

Answer (score 0):

The distinguishing property of the useless lines in this case is that they contain at least one vertex inside the polygonal obstacles.

There are many ways you might choose to decide if a vertex satisfies this condition but given that the coordinates come from a binary image, one of the most straightforward might be to check if the vertex comes within a pixel's distance of any point in `vo`:

```
[~,D] = knnsearch(vo,[vx(:),vy(:)]);
inObstacle = any(reshape(D,size(vx)) < 1);
plot(vx(:,~inObstacle),vy(:,~inObstacle),'-b');
```

If you cannot rely on the obstacles being filled with pixels (e.g. they may be hollow) then you probably need to determine which pixels belong to the same obstacle (perhaps using `kmeans` or `bwconncomp`) and then eliminate Voronoi edges that intrude into each object's convex hull. For a given obstacle made up of the pixels in `vo` listed by the linear indices `idx`:

```
K = convhull(vo(idx,1),vo(idx,2));
inObstacle = inpolygon(vx,vy,vo(idx(K),1),vo(idx(K),2));
```